# Help me understand this Strange C++ code

Tags: c++

This was a question in our old C++ exam. This code is driving me crazy, could anyone explain what it does and - especially - why?

```
int arr[3]={10,20,30};
int *arrp = new int;

(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
(arrp=&arr[0])++;

std::cout<<*arrp;
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty crappy C++ exam to me.

Comment: Did they take the exam questions from the IOCCC?

Comment: Jamming stuff into one line to "test" you is just crappy teaching. Sorry. Since people usually don't program like this.

Comment: It does answer if you understand pointers or not. This is a perfect example of compiling and tracing through with a debugger to help understand it.

Comment: I don't really want to waste time on this one but I think that two of the lines of code cause UB by writing to the same object twice without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @Matti: yes, the result of `+=` is an lvalue.

Comment: @Charles: Shouldn't have deleted my comment that hastily... I'd always thought that assignment operators return the right-size operand as a plain value. I guess you learn something everyday.

Comment: Why isn't the third line undefined behavior? Isn't arr[1] being modified and read twice between sequence points?

Comment: @user168715: I think it is UB.

Comment: @me: "I don't really want to waste time". Too late :( I've already been sucked in.

Comment: Regarding the meaning of this, I'm torn between "teachers ought know UB when it explodes into their faces" and "oh no, the cat's been on the keyboard again".

Comment: Nonetheless, I suppose the teacher expected someone to call 28. Wonder how he would treat a student pinning him down with UB :D

Comment: @Matthieu: When I was teaching C++, something like this would give the students a 5% bonus towards their overall credits for my course.

Answer (score 13):

This statement writes to the object `*(arr+1)` twice without an intervening sequence point so has *undefined behavior*.

```
(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
```

This statement writes to the object `arrp` twice without an intervening sequence point so has *undefined behavior*.

```
(arrp=&arr[0])++;
```

The code could result in anything happening.

Reference: ISO/IEC 14882:2003 5 [expr]/4: "Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."

Answer (score 9):

```
(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
```

arr + 1 - element with index 1 
*(arr + 1) - value of this element 
*(arr + 1) += 3 - increase by 3 

(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5 - increase by 5;

so arr[1] == 28

```
(arrp=&arr[0])++;
```

arr[0] - value of element 0
&arr[0] - address of element 0
arrp=&arr[0] - setting arrp to point to elem 0
(arrp=&arr[0])++ - set arr to point to elem 1

result: 28

Comment: But there is no sequence point between the `+= 3` and the `+= 5` and the both operate on the same object?

Comment: @Charles: pretty sure it's valid. Otherwise there'd be little point in the += operator (or any assignment operator) having a non-void return type. But looking through the standard I can't find anything to clearly support this

Comment: @jalf: The point of it returning an lvalue is so that you can take its address or call a function on it (implying a separate sequence point). Writing to it again is definitely not valid (IMHO), but there are other things that you can do with an lvalue.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
```

produces the same result as this (see footnote):

```
arr[1] += 3;
arr[1] += 5;
```

This line:

```
(arrp=&arr[0])++;
```

produces the same result as this (see footnote):

```
int* arrp = arr+1;
```

So this line:

```
std::cout<<*arrp
```

prints out `28`.

But this code leaks memory because `int *arrp = new int;` allocates a new `int` on the heap which will be lost on assignment by `(arrp=&arr[0])++;`

Footnote: Of course I'm assuming an absence of weirdness.

**Edit:** Apparently some of the lines in fact lead to undefined behavior, due to C++ Standard 5/4. So this really is a crappy exam question.

Comment: `(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;` is not identical to `arr[1] += 3; arr[1] += 5;` as you've introduced a sequence point in the second that isn't present in the first.

Comment: How would the operators be overloaded when none of the operands are user-defined types? What about the potential for undefined behavior in the original expressions?

Comment: I thought in this case the innermost expression is evaluated first (`arr+1`), then outwards due to the parentheses?

Comment: @In silico: Yes, that is how the expression must be evaluated but the two writes which are side-effects of the `+=` aren't separated from each other by a sequence point so the behavior is undefined, unless you have an argument as to why it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
int arr[3]={10,20,30}; // obvious?
int *arrp = new int; // allocated memory for an int

(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5; // (1)
(arrp=&arr[0])++; // (2)

std::cout<<*arrp; // (3)
```

**(1)**

`*(arr+1)` is the same as `arr[1]`, which means that `*(arr+1)+=3` will increase `arr[1]` by 3, so `arr[1] == 23` now.

`(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5` means `arr[1]` is increased by another 5, so it will be `28` now.

**(2)**

`arrp` will pont to the address of the first element of `arr` (`arr[0]`). The pointer `arrp` will then be incremented, thus it will point to the second element after the entire statement is executed.

**(3)**

Prints what `arrp` points to: the second element of `arr`, meaning `28`.

Comment: How do you know arr[1] is increased by **another 5**? It is just as likely the increment of 5 replaces the increment of 3. Or perhaps the increment of 3 replaces the increment of 5. The sequence of the operations is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, remember that arrays can be interpreted as pointers

```
int arr[3]={10,20,30};
int *arrp = new int;
```

creates an array `arr` of three integers and an `int pointer` that gets assigned with a freshly allocated value.

Since assignment operators return a reference to the value that has been assigned in order to allow multi-assignment,

```
(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(arr+1)+=3;
*(arr+1)+=5;
```

`*(arr + 1)` refers to the first element of the array `arr`, therefore `arr[1]` is effectively increased by eight.

`(arrp=&arr[0])++;` assigns the address of the first array element to `arrp` and afterward increments this pointer which now points to the second element (`arr[1]` again).

By dereferencing it in `std::cout<<*arrp`, you output `arr[1]` which now holds the value `20 + 3 + 5 = 28`.

So the code prints `28` (and furthermore creates a memory-leak since the `new int` initially assigned to `arrp` never gets `delete`d)

Comment: The two code blocks are not equivalent. You've changed the order of operations from undefined to defined by introducing a sequence point. In the code as specified, the increments can happen in any order, including interleaved (read 1, read 2, increment 1, increment 2, write 1, write 2), resulting in both increments not taking place.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer you by rewriting the code in a simpler way.

```
int arr[3]={10,20,30};
int *arrp = new int;

(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
(arrp=&arr[0])++;

std::cout<<*arrp;
```

=== equals ===

```
int arr[3]={10,20,30};//create array of 3 elements and assign them
int *arrp = new int;//create an integer pointer and allocate an int to it(useless)

//(*(arr+1)+=3)+=5;
arr[1] = arr[1] + 3;//arr[1] == arr+1 because it is incrementing the arr[0] pointer
arr[1] = arr[1] + 5;

//(arrp=&arr[0])++;
arrp = &arr[0];//point the integer pointer to the first element in arr[]
arrp++;//increment the array pointer, so this really is now pointing to arr[1]

std::cout<<*arrp;//just print out the value, which is arr[1]
```

I am assuming you understand pointers and basic c.